# Camera2: Remove Surface from already created CameraCaptureSession

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

I am creating an application which takes video from both front and rear cameras simultaneously. Both cameras are sending images to respective `ImageReader` for some processing. I have a `TextureView` as well to show preview from *any one* of the user desired camera.

So the capture session of camera showing preview has two surfaces `ImageReader` and `TextureView` and the other camera only has `ImageReader`.

Now, when user switches the camera **I want to remove the `TextureView`'s `Surface` from one `CameraCaptureSession` and add to other session**

**Is there any way I can remove a `Surface` from a `CameraCaptureSession` without closing the session?**

My code as of now (similar is for rear camera):

```
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
        mCaptureRequestBuilderFront = mCameraDeviceFront.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

        List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>();

        /* Make Surface out of texture as preview is shown on a Surface */
        Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        surfaces.add(surface);
        mCaptureRequestBuilderFront.addTarget(surface);

        /* Make Surface out of ImageReader to get images for processing */
        Surface readerSurface = mImageReaderFront.getSurface();
        surfaces.add(readerSurface);
        mCaptureRequestBuilderFront.addTarget(readerSurface);

        /* Create the Capture Session to start getting images from the camera */
        mCameraDeviceFront.createCaptureSession(
                surfaces
                , mSessionCallbackFront
                , mBackgroundHandler);
```

Comment: I am trying the following now: Having a global scope variable for Surfaces List passed to sessions, will remove/add surface as required. Will update if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  You can certainly stop targeting the TextureView in your requests, but another session can't include the TextureView in its set of outputs unless the first session is recreated without it.

If you want to make this smoother, you'd basically need to implement your own buffer routing - for example, have a GL stage that has two input SurfaceTextures and renders into the TextureView SurfaceTexture, and then connect each camera to a SurfaceTexture.  Then you write a pixel shader that just copies either Surface Texture A or B into the output, depending on which camera is active.

That's a lot of boilerplate, but is pretty efficient.

On recent Android releases, you could try using a pair of ImageReaders for camera and a ImageWriter to a TextureView, using the [ImageReader constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html#newInstance(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20long)) that accepts a usage flag, with usage flag [GPU_SAMPLED_IMAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/HardwareBuffer.html#USAGE_GPU_SAMPLED_IMAGE).  And then queue an Image from the ImageReader you currently have active to the ImageWriter to the TextureView.